# TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I need to find elements on a page by looking for text(), so I use xlsx as a database with all the texts that will be searched.

It turns out that it is showing the error reported in the title of the publication, this is my code:

```
        search_num = str("'//a[contains(text()," + '"' + row[1] + '")' + "]'")
        print(search_num)
        xPathnum = self.chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, search_num)
        print(xPathnum.get_attribute("id"))
```

print(search_num) returns = `'//a[contains(text(),"0027341-66.2323.0124")]'`

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong, despite having similar posts on the forum, none of them solved my problem. Grateful for the attention

Comment: What is self.chrome? Are you sure it is not self.driver?

Comment: self.chrome = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=self.options) @Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot more quotes appear, Use python `format()` function to substitute the variable.

```
search_num ="//a[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(row[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have extra quotes here
`str("'//a[contains(text()," + '"' + row[1] + '")' + "]'")`

Try changing to `f"//a[contains(text(),'{row[1]}')]"`

Comment: It showed the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(text(),'0027341-66.2323.0124)']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: fixed the xpath